# Arquivo não abre ou não é reconhecido no localhost do Linux Fedora?

Tags: linux, apache, permissões, localhost

Na tela do terminal, as permissões estão corretas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém no meu localhost, a página está abrindo com erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém na tela da IDE, ele está lá também, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A dúvida, é, como eu faço o meu localhost reconhecer que esse arquivo existe no sistema?

já tentei usar o comando `sudo service httpd restart`, mas nada mudou, alguém sabe outra coisa que é preciso fazer?

**Basicamente a permissão está:**

1. dono (leitura e escrita) 6
2. grupo (leitura e escrita) 6
3. outros (leitura) 4

Os outros arquivos da lista, estão abrindo normalmente, só esse que não:
`gerenciar-premios-imprensa.phtml`

Comment: Você tem certeza de que está passando o caminho correto do arquivo? Tente passar o caminho absoluto dele ao invés de passar o caminho relativo ao arquivo que está tentando incluí-lo.

Comment: Tenho certeza, porque que ele está no mesmo local que os demais, e os outros abrem normalmente.

Comment: Todas as views são chamadas através do método. Estou usando o Zend Framework 1.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome do arquivo está incorreto.

Você está tentando incluir:

```
gerenciar-premios-imprensa.phtml
```

... mas o nome com o qual você salvou o arquivo é:

```
gerenciar-premios-impresa.phtml
```

Está faltando um `n` no meio.

Comment: Obrigado, é isso mesmo, putz, que cego! valeu!

Comment: - Você só pode aceitar a resposta em 7 minutos... depois eu marco, lá, valeu!